# Java: Send POST curl command to send a message in slack

Tags: java, curl

I have a selenium java automation and I need to send the following CURL command in my java code:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Test"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/YYY/ZZZ
```

I tried some solutions I found here like:

```
String command = "curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Test"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/YYY/ZZZ";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

And also this one:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/YYY/ZZZ");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "test"));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

The script runs, but nothing happens (no message/warning/error on Eclipse console), it just runs and pass successfully, but the message is not sent on Slack channel. If I run this same curl command in my linux terminal, the message is sent on Slack.

I'm still learning Java, so probably I'm doing something wrong very obviously.

Comment: In the second case, what do you get in the response?  Specifically, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode().  Does this API require authentication?

Comment: I tried your code, I even tried System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());, but nothing is printed in the console

Comment: @wg2moiLi8K425oUo It can be problem in the your slack url. I tried the same thing and it gives http 302

Comment: Ah this slack URL I posted in the question is a dummy one, because it's my workplace webhook so I can't post here, it was just an example.

Comment: I did not use your URL, I used from the https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks here

Comment: Got it ... I believe my slack url is correct because if I run this curl command in my linux terminal using my url, it works correctly

Comment: Is there any proxy which you should use or you should try with http protocol instead of https ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200726/discussion-between-wg2moili8k425ouo-and-hatice).

Answer (score 1):

I could finally made it to work:

```
String[] command = new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", "curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{\"text\":\"test\"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/AAA/BBB/CCC"};
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
```